# Avoid n+1 queries in django admin nested detail inlines

Tags: django, django-admin

I currently have a model in my admin with a child inline:

```
class ChildInline(admin.StackedInline):
   # displays fields that load other associations

@admin.register(Statistic)
class ParentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   inlines = (
        ChildInline,
   )
```

This results in an n+1 problem, that could easily be solved with prefetch_related if I could get it to work!
I've tried to use prefetch_related on both the child and the parent get_queryset method (among other things) with no luck in eliminating the n+1 issue.

Anyone have any working code for this?

Comment: Have you tried overriding the `get_queryset()` routine in your ParentAdmin class? You can add your `prefetch_related()` call there.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `get_queryset()` method to fetch relational fields, one possible solution could be...

in `views.py:`

```
def get_queryset(self):
    single_related_fields = [field for field in self.model._meta.fields\
        if field.get_internal_type() in ['ForeignKey', 'OneToOneField']]
    multiple_related_fields = [field for field in self.model._meta.fields\
        if field.get_internal_type() in ['ManyToManyField']]
    return Model.objects.all().\
            select_related(single_related_fields).\
            prefetch_related(multiple_related_fields)
```

if self.model is giving out an error, Please include model in your viewset or try using self.__ class__.model which may solve the problem

You can try to tweak the fields as per your wish, such as including `ManyToOneField` or excluding certain fields.

Using `prefetch_related` on one-to-one or foreign keys is not advisable. You should use `select_related` for these which takes only db query to fetch the keys.

[select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)
[prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)